# Filling in a completely empty list of lists in an arbitrary order

Tags: python, list

I am trying to fill an `NxN` list of lists in python. In a way that if seen as a 2D array, first the main diagonal is filled and then other operations are done with other elements (not relevant here). So for example if we have `dyn_arr=[[[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []]]` in the beginning, it should first turn into: `[[[1], [], []], [[], [1], []], [[], [], [1]]]`. I assumed this code might do it:

```
dyn_arr = [[[]]* N] * N
idx_set = []
for pointer in range(N):
    pointer_pair = [0, pointer]
    while pointer_pair[0] < N and pointer_pair[1] < N:
        if pointer_pair[0] == pointer_pair[1]:
            dyn_arr[pointer_pair[0]][pointer_pair[1]]=[1]
        pointer_pair[0] += 1
        pointer_pair[1] += 1
```

But it outputs `[[[1], [1], [1]], [[1], [1], [1]], [[1], [1], [1]]]`. Can somebody please explain me what is going on and how I should correct it?

Comment: You have the same reference(s) that are duplicated `N` times, so when you modify any of them, you're actually modifying all of them.

Comment: Why do you increase pointer _pair[1] while your outside cycle does that?

Comment: @UpmostScarab, I am filling in the array in a specific order (diagonally).

Comment: @Cupitor Yes. But first you iterate by pointer and assign pointer_pair[1] to pointer and then later you add one to it. So I think you go through list like N*(N-1) times

Comment: @UpmostScarab, not that is not the case. You can run the code with a print. The if doesn't run more than 3 times. The reason was what \@Alfe mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when creating lists using the multiplication operator.  This way will multiply the *references* to the objects in the list; it will not create copies!  So, if you create a list of lists using `a = [[]] * 3`, this will create a list of three elements which are all the same empty array.  Changing it (using `.append()`) will change this one same list which is referenced in all three elements of the outer list:

```
a = [[]] * 3
print a  # prints "[[], [], []]"
a[0].append(4)
print a  # prints "[[4], [4], [4]]"
print a[0] is a[1]  # prints "True"
```

You should always create lists of lists using a list comprehension:

```
# instead of dyn_arr = [[[]]* N] * N use:
dyn_arr = [ [ [] for _i in range(N) ] for _j in range(N) ]
```

The result will look the same right after creation, but this version creates *new* arrays for each entry instead of additional references.

This should solve your issues resulting from the original error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

N = 3
z = np.zeros((N,N))
rng = np.arange(N)
z[rng, rng] = 1
print z
```

I hope this helps
:)